# SOA vs Database

Tags: .net, wcf, json, soap, soa

I have been reading up on WCF and coming from a background where we didn't use web services that much I am trying to figure out the comparative advantages of using a Webservice over a database.  I can definitely that when you are trying to interface with a with an outside application say to auto order materials from your inventory management application to the vendors order placement application.  But internally I am trying to see the usefulness.

Communicating with two different applications in different languages on two different systems internally can be done on a central database.  Say you have a customer places an order you application written in Java stores it in your MySql database and then the person on the shipping floor receives the order through his application that checks for new orders automatically from MySql through the program.  So I am not sure where web services fit into the whole scheme of things internally.  What are some examples of times when you would want to use a SOA over a Database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure if you can even compare SOA (such a broad term), with database. The definition for SOA in Wikipedia is

> Service-oriented architecture (SOA) is
>   a flexible set of design principles
>   used during the phases of systems
>   development and integration in
>   computing.A system based on a SOA will package functionality as a suite of interoperable services that can be used within multiple, separate systems from several business domains. *Quoted from Wikipedia*

So its not just about two applications that talk to a database as you have stated. It's about a broader look in to your whole business system. The SOA layer will provide services to all the upstream applications that can be considered as consumers. The SOA layer might be communicating with any number of databases. May be to a MySQL, SQL Server, Informix all at the same time. The consumer of these SOA layer won't have to bother about the downstream systems and he can use the business functionalities available in the services.

Hope this gets you a hint on what SOA is all about. For a good read on what SOA is go through this Wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture

Comment: Yet another nice article about SOA in msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480021.aspx

Comment: That hit the nail on the head. Thank you!! You are right it is a broad term.  SOA seem to work very closely together and can globalize a lot of business process.

Answer (score 2):

Using a database for integration is many times not a very good idea

1. when working with a data base you access the data layer of the other application - you can't access the business layer (unless implemented as stored procedures)
2. when accessing directly the database you can't change the DB schema with out updating the other applications

these are just a few examples - there are more

Answer (score 1):

You would usually use a database as the storage mechanism for your service - it's not a choice of SOA vs Database - it's a question of "do I need to expose my data/service outside the boundaries of my organisation?"  Yes? -> use a service.  No? -> Just have a database.

Comment: So, do you mean to say SOA is not a preferred option within the organization?

Comment: soa is still a valid choice within your org, but it's a tradeoff: more time to implement a service, but more future-proof in case you may need to expose your data outside the org in the future :)